# C Makefile I'm stuck

Tags: c, makefile

Ok I'm doing Zed Shaws Learn C the hard way. I'm stuck on lesson 2 where you have to create a makefile. I create the makefile in my directory as he says I add the code, but when I run make this is the result

```
$ make clean
Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I don't know how to fix the error. The code he has you type is

```
CFLAGS=-Wall    -g

clean:
    rm  -f  ex1
```

I'm not spacing either just hitting tab as instructed from the book.

Comment: It's not lying: You need a TAB character before `rm -f ex1`.

Comment: Check that your editor is using tab characters and not just putting in 4 spaces. Some editors do this as many people like to not mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: @devnull got it, you must start the command with a tab... not spaces and no tabs in the actual command. Also, make sure your editor is not converting tabs into spaces.

Comment: Alright I'll try that and let you all know.

Comment: I got it , It was a problem with my editors spacing it kept adding spaces instead of tab . Thanks Guys !